# Select based on field in another table

Tags: mysql

Table1
user,city

Table2
user,friends

I want to `select * from Table1` for one specific user and all his friends (who are also users in Table1).

Tried this and it found all data but gave multiple rows for `WHERE Table1.user = '$user'` even though every username is unique.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Table1.user = '$user'
OR
(Table2.user = '$user' and Table2.friends = Table1.user)
```

Many thanks

Comment: You're going to get one row for $user for each ($user, $user's friends) row because user = $user for all those rows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially have two different queries (select user 1's info, select user 1's friends' info). You can combine them with a UNION.

```
SELECT
  table1.user,
  table1.city
FROM
  table1
INNER JOIN
  table2
ON
  table1.user = table2.friends
WHERE
  table2.friends = '$user'

UNION

SELECT
  user,
  city
FROM
  table1
WHERE
  user = '$user'
```

Comment: It's perfect! Can I add an ORDER BY for the combined select?

Comment: Found the answer: ORDER BY 2; orders by the second result i.e. city. Many thanks for your help!!!

Comment: ORDER BY 2 does not order by the second result, it orders by the constant number 2, which is not really an ordering. If it produced the right result, it was by chance and won't continue to if you start deleting/inserting new rows. If you actually want to order the entire result set, wrap the whole query in `SELECT * FROM (the existing query) ORDER BY city`

Comment: If I try that is says 'Invalid query: Every derived table must have its own alias'

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (the existing query) t1 ORDER BY city`

Comment: Great. Please click the checkmark graphic to the left of my answer to mark it as correct.